# Receiving 404 while using register3 API.

Tags: yodlee

I am using live account for Yodlee.
How do I proceed to create user using credential I received from Yodlee team and REST api url?
I have used this url.

> {MY LIVE REST API URL}/v1.0/jsonsdk/UserRegistration/register3.

But it showing 404 page not found.
I want tutorial to be used to proceed live Yodlee account.
I have tried test drive and felt comfortable with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/` URL then you won't be able to use this API. As this is developer's environment and Yodlee do provides 5 pre-registered users which you can get under Developer Info page(Available once you'll login to `www.developer.yodlee.com` and click on **MyProfile** link).

Else if this is not a case and if you have access to Yodlee Customer Care tool then we request to raise a Service Request with the problem description which you are facing.